# Select the element next the selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I have next code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="select_big" name="additional_field" id="<?=$field['id'];?>" required>
      <option value="0">Выберите значение</option>
      ...
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="select_big" name="additional_field" id="<?=$field['id'];?>" required>
      <option value="0">Выберите значение</option>
      ...
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="select_big" name="additional_field" id="<?=$field['id'];?>" required>
      <option value="0">Выберите значение</option>
      ...
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="select_big" name="additional_field" id="<?=$field['id'];?>" required>
      <option value="0">Выберите значение</option>
      ...
  </td>
</tr>
```

When I select the second "select" element, I need to disable all the next one.
If I select 1 need to disable 3 and 4, if I select 2 I need to disable only 4.
Count of element could be different.

How I can get all elements next the select?

I try next:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("[name=additional_field]").change(function(e) {
    field_data = '#' this.id.replace(/[* .]/g, "\\$&");
      $(field_data).parent().parent().nextAll().each(function(i) {
        console.log($(this)('[name=additional_field]'));
      });
  });
</script>
```

But I receive next error:
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Help me please.

Comment: made mistake, if I change 1 I need to block 3 and 4.

Comment: Your updated requirement can be handled easily by @dfsq's solution (just needs a minor tweak to add one to the index).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it simpler without confusing traversal of the parent nodes:

```
var $sel = $('.select_big').change(function() {
    $sel.filter(':gt(' + $sel.index(this) + ')').prop('disabled', +$(this).val());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VFcF9/

It will also reenable selectboxes if you select default option back.

Comment: +1. Nice. I like that you provided code that re-enables the select elements if the value is changed, although you may like to try this sequence: (1) select non-zero item in second drop-down; (2) select non-zero item in first drop-down; (3) select zero item in first drop-down. (This re-enables the third drop-down when it shouldn't.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Ok, got it. Interesting bug, thank you! Will try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The error you were getting is because of this line:

```
$(this)('[name=additional_field]')
```

The first part, `$(this)`, returns a jQuery object, and that object is not a function so you can't follow it with more parentheses.

As for your requirement to disable all of the following select elements, perhaps:

```
$("[name=additional_field]").change(function(e) {
  $(this).closest("tr").nextAll("tr").find("[name=additional_field]").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: This block only the next element

Comment: Really? It [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/K8ZNF/), though I would recommend that you use some variation on what @dfsq posted rather than this. (I would delete my answer as a duplicate of Joseph's except that I'm the only one who explained the error you were getting.)

Comment: Yes, I agree a `+1` for explaining the reason behind the error.

Answer (score 0):

[This should do it](http://jsfiddle.net/ckSQJ/)

```
$("[name=additional_field]").change(function(e) {

  var f = $(this).closest('tr')             //find the closest parent tr
                 .nextAll('tr')             //find all tr that follows
                 .find('select.select_big') //from them, get all select

  //f should be all the selects the follow what changed

});
```

Comment: Now it tied to the class name, not the name?

And you have it done in a geometric progression.

Comment: @user2264941 selectors are optional, you *can* modify them. Geometric progression? I just picked all that came next.

Comment: My mistake, no progression.